# Visual Studio Skipping a project when debugging (no issues reported)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have a controller that uses a class in project named "Logica" to perform some file system management. This class in the "Logica" project, after performing its management taks calls a class in another project called "Dados" to register the operation in the Database. So the order, Controller > Logica.dll > Dados.dll. The problem is that when debug my solution, the Logica project is being skipped. Visual Studio 2017 doesn't complain of any issues. The breakpoints show as red dots but it never gets hit. The code in Logica.dll executes normally. The debugger operation performs as this controller >> Dados.dll (I am telling what seems like to me).

I will show a picture of the call stack. Excuse me for the bad picture, I am tired of VS Debugger problems.

[image]

I've tried clean the project, Restart VS, change the class name.

Comment: When I mean skip a project I mean skip the break points, the code executes normally.

Comment: I've tried to do more tests with other methods on the classes on the Logica project and the hit points are not being hit in that project and VS DOESN'T COMAPLAIN AT ALL!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that Visual Studio 2017 reseted the configuration of the project. Right clicking the project >> properties >> build >> was set to Release and code optimization was also enabled. I had set the configuration to Debug and code optimization to disabled two weeks ago. In those circuntaces VS normally shows a notification at the break point but I didn't get those. Sigh... lost half a day in this. VS will always be this way.